# How to get android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION in android 10 for my device owner application using devicepolicymanager?

Tags: permissions, device-policy-manager, device-owner

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();

ComponentName adminComponentName = getComponentName(context);

boolean success = mDevicePolicyManager.setPermissionGrantState(
    adminComponentName, packageName, 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
    DevicePolicyManager.PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED
);
```

This is the code I am using to grant ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, but I am not getting it.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you have all location associated permissions requested and granted:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

```
mDevicePolicyManager.setPermissionGrantState(
    adminComponentName, packageName, 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    DevicePolicyManager.PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED
);
mDevicePolicyManager.setPermissionGrantState(
    adminComponentName, packageName, 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    DevicePolicyManager.PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED
);
mDevicePolicyManager.setPermissionGrantState(
    adminComponentName, packageName, 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
    DevicePolicyManager.PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED
);
```

Probably you dont need to set `COARSE` and `FINE` permissions both at the same time, but I prefer it to be less riscky in case in one of android versions its treated differently.

A permission ui in settings:

- having just `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission is translated to giving access to location api **only when app ui is opened** by user.
- having both `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` sets it to **granted**